# How to use by.css with Xpath and how to diferenciate both elements with identical paths/classes

Tags: html, css, xpath, protractor

I have this two xpaths:

```
 /html/body/ion-app/ng-component/ion-nav/page-settings/ion-content/div[2]/ion-grid/ion-row[2]/ion-col[1]/ion-input
    /html/body/ion-app/ng-component/ion-nav/page-settings/ion-content/div[2]/ion-grid/ion-row[2]/ion-col[2]/ion-input
```

How do i use them with element by.css to test with protractor?

And how to diferenciate when both paths are "equal" like the ones presented above and on the picture?

[image: both elements]

Answer (score 0):

You can not use xpath with `by.css`, and only with `by.xpath`

If you want to use equivalent css to the given xpath, it's very basic knowledge, look it up. Here is a very good source https://devhints.io/xpath

Even though the second question should have been a separate post, I'll answer that also. In your particular example, the input are not identical.

Xpath:

1. `//*[@ng-reflect-model="GG"]/input`
2. `//*[@ng-reflect-model="Test"]/input`

But in hypothetical scenario, when you have 2 elements with the same attributes, you can specify which occurrence to use - `(//xpath)[1]` (selects the first match), or say which child is that - `//xpath/to/firstChild[1]`